# SeatMap returning error 500 in production, exact same input as test environment

Tags: amadeus

Executing the exact same input in test.api.amadeus.com, I receive results. When executing it in production (exact same inputs, but changing the Authentication Token of course), I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

--------- TEST ENVIRONMENT - WORKS ---------

```
Request URL: https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/seatmaps
Request Method: POST
**Status Code: 200 OK**
Remote Address: 34.241.162.107:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 29 Jan 2020 23:27:11 GMT
Content-Type: application/vnd.amadeus+json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Ama-Internal-Message-Version: 14.1
Ama-Request-Id: 0001DSCPD4W6HB
Content-Encoding: gzip
Ama-Gateway-Request-Id: rrt-018b7024434a97214-a-eu-16978-374312555-4
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, accept, Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Server: Amadeus
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
POST /v1/shopping/seatmaps HTTP/1.1
Host: test.api.amadeus.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1108
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer **REMOVED**
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/vnd.amadeus+json
Origin: http://localhost:15496
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:15496/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6
{"data":[{"type":"flight-offer","id":"1","source":"GDS","instantTicketingRequired":false,"nonHomogeneous":false,"oneWay":false,"lastTicketingDate":"2020-02-01","numberOfBookableSeats":1,"itineraries":[{"duration":"PT13H5M","segments":[{"departure":{"iataCode":"YUL","at":"2020-08-22T13:10:00"},"arrival":{"iataCode":"NRT","terminal":"1","at":"2020-08-23T15:15:00"},"carrierCode":"AC","number":"5","aircraft":{"code":"789"},"operating":{"carrierCode":"AC"},"duration":"PT13H5M","id":"1","numberOfStops":0,"blacklistedInEU":false}]}],"price":{"currency":"EUR","total":"597.54","base":"498.00","fees":[{"amount":"0.00","type":"SUPPLIER"},{"amount":"0.00","type":"TICKETING"}],"grandTotal":"597.54"},"pricingOptions":{"fareType":["PUBLISHED"],"includedCheckedBagsOnly":true},"validatingAirlineCodes":["AC"],"travelerPricings":[{"travelerId":"1","fareOption":"STANDARD","travelerType":"ADULT","price":{"currency":"EUR","total":"597.54","base":"498.00"},"fareDetailsBySegment":[{"segmentId":"1","cabin":"ECONOMY","fareBasis":"AKWCJO","brandedFare":"STANDARD","class":"A","includedCheckedBags":{"quantity":2}}]}]}]}
```

--------- PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT - ERROR ---------

```
Request URL: https://api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/seatmaps
Request Method: POST
**Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error**
Remote Address: 34.241.162.69:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 29 Jan 2020 23:24:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/vnd.amadeus+json
Content-Length: 382
Connection: keep-alive
Ama-Gateway-Request-Id: rrt-0ba2dd5701eb81dae-b-eu-22940-376370160-5
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, x-requested-with, accept, Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Server: Amadeus
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
POST /v1/shopping/seatmaps HTTP/1.1
Host: api.amadeus.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1108
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer **REMOVED**
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/vnd.amadeus+json
Origin: http://localhost:15496
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:15496/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,pt;q=0.6
{"data":[{"type":"flight-offer","id":"1","source":"GDS","instantTicketingRequired":false,"nonHomogeneous":false,"oneWay":false,"lastTicketingDate":"2020-02-01","numberOfBookableSeats":6,"itineraries":[{"duration":"PT13H5M","segments":[{"departure":{"iataCode":"YUL","at":"2020-08-22T13:45:00"},"arrival":{"iataCode":"NRT","terminal":"1","at":"2020-08-23T15:50:00"},"carrierCode":"AC","number":"5","aircraft":{"code":"789"},"operating":{"carrierCode":"AC"},"duration":"PT13H5M","id":"1","numberOfStops":0,"blacklistedInEU":false}]}],"price":{"currency":"EUR","total":"599.78","base":"500.00","fees":[{"amount":"0.00","type":"SUPPLIER"},{"amount":"0.00","type":"TICKETING"}],"grandTotal":"599.78"},"pricingOptions":{"fareType":["PUBLISHED"],"includedCheckedBagsOnly":true},"validatingAirlineCodes":["AC"],"travelerPricings":[{"travelerId":"1","fareOption":"STANDARD","travelerType":"ADULT","price":{"currency":"EUR","total":"599.78","base":"500.00"},"fareDetailsBySegment":[{"segmentId":"1","cabin":"ECONOMY","fareBasis":"AKWCJO","brandedFare":"STANDARD","class":"A","includedCheckedBags":{"quantity":2}}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Has this worked before? If it hasn't, you probably need certification to use the endpoint in production. I don't know about the REST endpoints, but the SOAP endpoints each require certification by Amadeus before they are unlocked.

Comment: @Heki Thanks. The documentation does not talk about any certification, only Authentication Token, which I provided (and was authenticated, otherwise it gives an authentication error).

Comment: I haven't seen it described anywhere that an endpoint would require certification, but I know that my company have been through several certification rounds as we expanded our systems.

Answer (score 0):

Received a reply from Amadeus support:

> Thanks for reporting this. We are aware of the issue with SeatMaps API
>   in production. Our technical team is already investigating and looking
>   for a solution.

Comment: That's good to know. I will monitor this question in case we too should need to use the seat map.